# Namespace standards with ISAPI folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint, namespaces, standards

> 1. namespace Project.ISAPI.ProjectFolderWithServices.Solution
> 2. namespace Project.ProjectFolderWithServices.Solution

So, should i use first one? Should I take into consideration that sharepoint mapped ISAPI folder in my namespace's policy? Or ingore it? How it looks in your solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the second version:

> Project.ProjectFolderWithServices.Solution

In my opinion the name `ISAPI` does not belong to your namespace structure. Of course there are always different architecture philosophies. But ISAPI is something sharepoint specific and has nothing to do with your project.
Therefor I would not include ISAPI in your namespace.

Comment: yeah, my understatements was born by vs tools to clean your code. They think about mapped folders as normal folders so it can makes them stupid. But! if solution doesnt have mapped folder then it just wont work! isnt it nice to show it in your namespace to make things more readable?

Comment: Well, if you know enough about sharepoint that a webservice is in the ISAPI folder, then I think it won't help you. Also in the other case, if know nothing about sharepoint and see "ISAPI" in the namespace you ask yourself "What the hell does ISAPI mean?". I would not use it

Comment: Your arguments was right answere accepted :) pls dont kick im (chuck norris )

Comment: Hehe, dont worry. Even chuck norris needs a rest from time to time :P